# How to hide custom layer loss in Keras fit output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm using a complicated custom layer to train my Keras model, and my console prints metrics for all my custom layers as follow. Is there any way to suppress these (`dense_2_x_loss` and `dense_2_x_acc`)? I still want my model `loss`

I understand the `verbose` argument in `model.fit()`, but I don't want to silent the metrics and I don't care about the progress bar.

```
191/313 [=================>............] - ETA: 4:47 - loss: 219.7755 - dense_2_loss: 7.1290 - dense_2_1_loss: 8.7435 - dense_2_2_loss: 8.7449 - dense_2_3_loss: 8.7680 - dense_2_4_loss: 8.7945 - dense_2_5_loss: 8.5691 - dense_2_6_loss: 8.7035 - dense_2_7_loss: 8.3155 - dense_2_8_loss: 8.1388 - dense_2_9_loss: 7.9680 - dense_2_10_loss: 7.4622 - dense_2_11_loss: 7.0953 - dense_2_12_loss: 6.8599 - dense_2_13_loss: 6.4530 - dense_2_14_loss: 6.0404 - dense_2_15_loss: 5.6781 - dense_2_16_loss: 5.3687 - dense_2_17_loss: 4.9732 - dense_2_18_loss: 4.6142 - dense_2_19_loss: 4.3432 - dense_2_20_loss: 4.1127 - dense_2_21_loss: 3.8558 - dense_2_22_loss: 3.5770 - dense_2_23_loss: 3.3686 - dense_2_24_loss: 3.0425 - dense_2_25_loss: 2.8465 - dense_2_26_loss: 2.5968 - dense_2_27_loss: 2.4009 - dense_2_28_loss: 2.2367 - dense_2_29_loss: 2.0981 - dense_2_30_loss: 1.9240 - dense_2_31_loss: 1.8475 - dense_2_32_loss: 1.6736 - dense_2_33_loss: 1.5722 - dense_2_34_loss: 1.4739 - dense_2_35_loss: 1.4386 - dense_2_36_loss: 1.3244 - dense_2_37_loss: 1.2336 - dense_2_38_loss: 1.1778 - dense_2_39_loss: 1.0939 - dense_2_40_loss: 1.0619 - dense_2_acc: 0.0000e+00 - dense_2_1_acc: 0.0000e+00 - dense_2_2_acc: 0.0000e+00 - dense_2_3_acc: 0.0000e+00 - dense_2_4_acc: 4.9084e-04 - dense_2_5_acc: 0.0031 - dense_2_6_acc: 0.0178 - dense_2_7_acc: 0.0443 - dense_2_8_acc: 0.0776 - dense_2_9_acc: 0.1135 - dense_2_10_acc: 0.1561 - dense_2_11_acc: 0.1973 - dense_2_12_acc: 0.2376 - dense_2_13_acc: 0.2801 - dense_2_14_acc: 0.3249 - dense_2_15_acc: 0.3704 - dense_2_16_acc: 0.4103 - dense_2_17_acc: 0.4522 - dense_2_18_acc: 0.4930 - dense_2_19_acc: 0.5278 - dense_2_20_acc: 0.5571 - dense_2_21_acc: 0.5874 - dense_2_22_acc: 0.6207 - dense_2_23_acc: 0.6512 - dense_2_24_acc: 0.6823 - dense_2_25_acc: 0.7071 - dense_2_26_acc: 0.7336 - dense_2_27_acc: 0.7567 - dense_2_28_acc: 0.7762 - dense_2_29_acc: 0.7942 - dense_2_30_acc: 0.8135 - dense_2_31_acc: 0.8266 - dense_2_32_acc: 0.8429 - dense_2_33_acc: 0.8559 - dense_2_34_acc: 0.8665 - dense_2_35_acc: 0.8748 - dense_2_36_acc: 0.8860 - dense_2_37_acc: 0.8940 - dense_2_38_acc: 0.9017 - dense_2_39_acc: 0.9094 - dense_2_40_acc: 0.9157
```

Desired output:

```
191/313 [=================>............] - ETA: 4:47 - loss: 219.7755
```

My model.compile() if that helps

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tqdm` progress bar instead.

```
from tqdm.keras import TqdmCallback
...
model.fit(..., verbose=0, callbacks=[TqdmCallback(verbose=2)])
```

From the [TqdmCallback](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/keras/) documentation:

> verbose : int
>
> 0: epoch, 1: batch (transient), 2: batch. [default: 1].
> Will be set to 0 unless both data_size and batch_size are given.
> tqdm_class : optional tqdm class to use for bars [default:
> tqdm.auto.tqdm].